# Page Loading Issue

Tags: performance

I created a test page that has the below code
page link is site.com/testing

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<?php wp_footer();?>
```

Page taking much time to load.
GTmetrix can't able to give result of page speed,since it through analysis error

Any help would be appreciate.